# Regular Expression, Match ccurrenced text

Tags: nsregularexpression

I have this string :

```
*Field1=0(1936-S),Field13=0(2),Field2=0(),Field4=0(19.01.17),Field3=0(),Field5700=0(),Field5400=0(KS),Field14=0(21)*
```

And I need store n-th value of FieldN so I tried this:
`(?<=Field[0-9]=0){4}?.*?(?=,)`

This give me (1936-S) when I put *N=4*, I expect *19.01.17*.

Can you help me please?

Comment: `(?<=Field[0-9]=0){4}?.*?(?=,)` does not work at all, you cannot quantify a zero-width assertion. Your `Field` has a number after it: why not leverage it? Try [`Field4=0\(\K[^,)]+`](https://regex101.com/r/h2raiA/1)

Comment: i am not using Field4=0\(\K[^,)]+ becouse i need to find in this "array" 4th occurenced field and select the value. For example in another string there can be Field8

Comment: Are you using it in Swift? You used nsregularexpression iOS tag, that's why I am asking.

Comment: Try [`^\*(?:Field[0-9]+=0\([^)]*\),){3}Field[0-9]+=0\(\K[^)]*`](https://regex101.com/r/1FDRuP/1) (or [this one](https://regex101.com/r/1FDRuP/2) with a capturing group).

Comment: working, thank you

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) since you reached 15 rep points and are now entitles to upvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^\*(?:Field[0-9]+=0\([^)]*\),){3}Field[0-9]+=0\(\K[^)]*
```

([demo](https://regex101.com/r/1FDRuP/1)) or a capturing group based pattern:

```
^\*(?:Field[0-9]+=0\([^)]*\),){3}Field[0-9]+=0\(([^)]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1FDRuP/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `\*` - a `*` char
- `(?:Field[0-9]+=0\([^)]*\),){3}` - 3 sequences of:

  - `Field` - a `Field` substring
  - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
  - `=0\(` - a `=0(` substring
  - `[^)]*` - any 0+ chars other than `)`
  - `\),`  - a `),` substring
- `Field[0-9]+=0\(` - a `Field` subtring followed with 1+ digits, and then `=0(` substring
- `([^)]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `)`.